# What the difference between these two API calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to upload an image.
Normally I use axios call api. Since This call is not working with axios I tried with fetch.

I want to know what the difference between these two

Here are these two.

Axios  // **API CALL WITH NOT SUCCESSFUL WITH THIS ONE**

```js
axios
  .post(
    "userapi/UpdateUserProfileImage",
    {
      body: createFormData(photo, {}),
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.response.data.Message));
```

Here is the fetch method. // this will successful

```js
fetch("userapi/UpdateUserProfile", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  }),
  body: createFormData(photo, {}),
})
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("upload succes", res);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("upload error", error);
  });
```

What the difference between these two?

Here is the error when I use axios to call API.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: Where is this code running? In the browser, Node or some other device (eg react-native)?

Comment: Is server obtains same data in both cases?

Comment: A simple typo but one that seems very prevalent. Don't wrap the Axios `data` param in an object. You can generally omit the content-type header for both requests as well. You really only need `axios.post(url, createFormData(photo, {}))`

Comment: Your End Point seems to be different. In axios - `UpdateUserProfileImage` and in fetch it is - `UpdateUserProfile`

Comment: Well, the error is from the server message is sent from the server, so it's sort of difficult to figure this out. Try it in a request client like Postman, and when it works, convert it to Axios one by one.